# Two different SSL certificates with one ip and same port but different host headers (IIS 8)

Tags: ssl, iis, certificate

I have IIS 8 and I have two website with two different domain names.
I have for each domain it's SSL certificate, but I only have one IP address.
Is it possible to attached each website it's own SSL certificate when I'm using the same IP address for both sites?
When I do it one of the sites is working fine, for the other one I get the SSL key of the first site.

Thanks
Bar

Comment: Here you are: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27791857/2879900

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with [server name indication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability).

IE 6 era clients do not support SNI. No big deal as they are end of life and [98+% of the browsers left support SNI](https://caniuse.com/#feat=sni).